# Batch file - Run only where 2 strings are in the directory name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to move all the files to the root directory from all the subdirectories only when the directory name doesn't have the sent or files. Any help?

```
for /r "c:\example" %1 in (.) do if /i not "%~nx1"=="Sent" move "%~f1\*.txt" "c:\example"
```

Comment: And if the same file name appears in multiple child folders, you want... what?

Comment: No directories are under the subdirectories. :) Thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set unwanted=\sent\files\
for /R "c:\example" %%a in (.) do if "!unwanted:\%%~Na\=!" == "%unwanted%" move "%%a\*.txt" "c:\example"
```

Comment: Ok, is moving the files but it still moving from the sent or/and files directory

Comment: Are you using it as a Batch file? This does NOT work from the command line.

Comment: Yes, in a batch file.